# Having Issue in Access Query getting unique values with max()

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that pulls in information from two tables and lists the most recently added entry for each unique value in the `OrderNumber` field. I thought it was working but I must have changed something because now it's displaying everything instead of the most recent for each order number:

*Note that the date actually displays the time as well but it changed when I pasted it into Stack Overflow.

This is how I want the data to display:

```
Job    Order Number Spool                   Status  Location    Modified
43400011    1371246 00040                   00721   DEASLEY     29-Oct-16
43400011    1371248 00042                   00721   DEASLEY     29-Oct-16
43400011    1386582 00059                   00721   CPERRY      29-Oct-16
43400011    1386584 00061                   00721   DEASLEY     29-Oct-16
43400011    1405367 00194                   00721   DEASLEY     29-Oct-16
61400046    1432157 00329                   00661   tsanchez    17-Oct-16
61400046    1432158 00330                   00661   tsanchez    17-Oct-16
```

But instead it comes out like this:

```
Job    Order Number Spool                   Status  Location    Modified
43400011    1371246 00040                   00721   DEASLEY     29-Oct-16
43400011    1371248 00042                   00721   DEASLEY     29-Oct-16
43400011    1371248 00042                   00721   DEASLEY     29-Oct-16
43400011    1386582 00059                   00721   CPERRY      29-Oct-16
43400011    1386584 00061                   00721   DEASLEY     29-Oct-16
43400011    1405367 00194                   00721   DEASLEY     29-Oct-16
61400046    1432157 00329                   00661   tsanchez    17-Oct-16
61400046    1432158 00330                   00661   JIFFY       29-Oct-16
61400046    1432158 00330                   00661   DEASLEY     29-Oct-16
61400046    1432158 00330                   00661   tsanchez    17-Oct-16
```

My Query:

```
SELECT [Branch/plant] AS Job, SpoolReport.OrderNumber AS [Order Number], 
       [Spl #] AS Spool, [Comp#] AS Status, SpoolReport.Location, 
       SpoolReport.Modified
FROM SpoolReport, STATUS
WHERE (SpoolReport.OrderNumber = [STATUS]![Order #]) 
AND   (((SpoolReport.Modified) IN
           (SELECT Max(SpoolReport.Modified) 
            FROM SpoolReport 
            GROUP BY SpoolReport.OrderNumber)) 
AND   ((SpoolReport.Complete)=False));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider correlating your subquery to outer main query. Right now the `WHERE` clause looks at any date in the `GROUP BY` query not matching the row's *OrderNumber*. Below equates subquery to outer query's *OrderNumber*. Notice use of table aliases, *main* and *sub*, to organize the query's correlations:

```
SELECT main.[Branch/plant] AS Job, main.OrderNumber AS [Order Number], 
       main.[Spl #] AS Spool, main.[Comp#] AS Status, main.Location, 
       main.Modified
FROM SpoolReport main
INNER JOIN STATUS s 
    ON main.OrderNumber = s.[Order #]
WHERE ((main.Modified = 
           (SELECT Max(sub.Modified) 
            FROM SpoolReport sub
            WHERE sub.OrderNumber = main.OrderNumber)) 
   AND (main.Complete = False));
```

Even better, consider joining the aggregate query as a derived table (or as saved query):

```
SELECT main.[Branch/plant] AS Job, main.OrderNumber AS [Order Number], 
       main.[Spl #] AS Spool, main.[Comp#] AS Status, main.Location, 
       main.Modified
FROM (SpoolReport main
INNER JOIN STATUS s 
    ON main.OrderNumber = s.[Order #])
INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT sub.OrderNumber, Max(sub.Modified) As MaxModified
         FROM SpoolReport sub
         GROUP BY sub.OrderNumber) As dT
    ON main.OrderNumber = dT.OrderNumber
    AND main.Modified = dT.MaxModified
WHERE (main.Complete = False);
```